# JavaFX borderpane fxml issue

Tags: java, fxml

I'm doing an app in JavaFX and I've problem. The problem is in line 31. The border pane in BorderPaneMain.fxm has fx:id="borderPane"
Main.java:

```
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
    Locale.setDefault(new Locale("pl"));

    final String PATH = "/fxml/BorderPaneMain.fxml";

    FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource(PATH));
    loader.setController(this);

    ResourceBundle bundle = ResourceBundle.getBundle("bundles.messages");
    loader.setResources(bundle);

    BorderPane borderPane = loader.load(); //this is line 31
    Scene scene = new Scene(borderPane);

    primaryStage.setScene(scene);

    primaryStage.setTitle(bundle.getString("tittle.app"));
    primaryStage.show();
}
```

Errors:

```
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.constructLoadException(FXMLLoader.java:2597)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.access$100(FXMLLoader.java:103)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processAttribute(FXMLLoader.java:914)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$InstanceDeclarationElement.processAttribute(FXMLLoader.java:971)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$Element.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:220)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:744)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:2707)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2527)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2441)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2409)
at pl.karolkluczniok.facture.Main.start(Main.java:31)
at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$162(LauncherImpl.java:863)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$175(PlatformImpl.java:326)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$173(PlatformImpl.java:295)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$174(PlatformImpl.java:294)
at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$148(WinApplication.java:191)
```

BorderPaneMain.fxml: [Link do fxml](https://www.dropbox.com/s/gss2t4bfpxamygd/BorderPaneMain.fxml?dl=0)

[Project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZMiRY.jpg)

Comment: Your issue appears to be with fxml so to get any help you'll need to actually show us the fxml.

Comment: I've just edited the post